# Average Column Google Charts

Tags: charts, datatable, google-visualization

I need to create a column in a data table of averages from columns of source data table.

Is there away to do this? I see it is possible to find max and min of columns from source data table using the jdata.getColumnRange(Column#).max and  jdata.getColumnRange(Column#).min.

Below is my code of getting Max Values and Min Values, storing them into table. How do I do this for Average Value?

```
        // Set MAX VALUE of Table            
        // Set 'VAY' MAX VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(0, 1, jdata.getColumnRange(1).max);
        // Set 'VBY' MAX VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(1, 1, jdata.getColumnRange(2).max);
        // Set 'VCY' MAX VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(2, 1, jdata.getColumnRange(3).max);
        // Set 'KW3DO' MAX VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(3, 1, jdata.getColumnRange(4).max);
        // Set 'KVR3' MAX VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(4, 1, jdata.getColumnRange(5).max);
        // Set 'PF3' MAX VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(5, 1, jdata.getColumnRange(6).max);


        // Set MIN VALUE of Table       
        // Set 'VAY' MIN VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(0, 2, jdata.getColumnRange(1).min);
        // Set 'VBY' MIN VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(1, 2, jdata.getColumnRange(2).min);
        // Set 'VCY' MIN VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(2, 2, jdata.getColumnRange(3).min);
        // Set 'KW3DO' MIN VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(3, 2, jdata.getColumnRange(4).min);
        // Set 'KVR3' MIN VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(4, 2, jdata.getColumnRange(5).min);
        // Set 'PF3' MIN VALUE of Table
        data.setCell(5, 2, jdata.getColumnRange(1).min);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the [`group()`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) method to perform aggregations (<-- see link for details)

`group()` results in another `DataTable`

so you can access the values afterwards

```
// i.e. - get average column
console.log(groupData.getValue(0, 1));
```

see following working snippet, which draws a table chart to display the data,
before and after using `group()`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable({
      cols: [
        {label: 'Stooge', type: 'string'},
        {label: 'TV Appearances', type: 'number'}
      ]
    });

    data.addRows([
      ['Moe', 129],
      ['Larry', 132],
      ['Curly', 99],
      ['Shemp', 42]
    ]);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div0'));
    table.draw(data);

    var groupData = google.visualization.data.group(
      data,
      // group across entire table -- use modifier to return same value for every row
      [{column: 0, modifier: function () {return '';}, type: 'string'}],
      [
        // aggregation functions
        {column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.avg, type: 'number', label: 'Average'},
        {column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.count, type: 'number', label: 'Count'},
        {column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.min, type: 'number', label: 'Minimum'},
        {column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.max, type: 'number', label: 'Maximum'},
        {column: 1, aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum, type: 'number', label: 'Sum'},
        // custom aggregation function
        {column: 1, aggregation: doubleSum, type: 'number', label: 'Double Sum'}
      ]
    );

    function doubleSum(values) {
      var aggValue = 0;
      values.forEach(function (appearances) {
        aggValue += (appearances * 2);
      });
      return aggValue;
    }

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div1'));
    table.draw(groupData);

    // i.e. - get average
    console.log(groupData.getValue(0, 1));
  },
  packages: ['table']
});
```

```css
div {
  padding: 6px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table_div0"></div>
<div id="table_div1"></div>
```